# Replace variable with a string value in R

Tags: r, metaprogramming, nse

I would like to pass the name of a column name as a variable to a function.
Specifically, given the following code:

```
#------------------------------------------
# Create mock data
#------------------------------------------

DF1 = data.frame(colA = as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4, B = 1:5, C = 5:1)
DF2 = data.frame(B = 1:5, C = 5:1)

#------------------------------------------
# Sample function call
#------------------------------------------

colname <- "colA"

b_func <- function( my_dt1, my_dt2, my_col ) {    
  return( eval(substitute( cbind( variable = as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4, DF2 ), 
    list(variable = as.name(my_col)))) )
}

b_func( DF1, DF2, colname )
```

I would expect to get the following output:

```
        colA B C
1 2015-09-21 1 5
2 2015-09-22 2 4
3 2015-09-23 3 3
4 2015-09-24 4 2
5 2015-09-25 5 1
```

Instead I am getting the following output where instead of `"colA"` I am getting `"variable"`.

```
    variable B C
1 2015-09-21 1 5
2 2015-09-22 2 4
3 2015-09-23 3 3
4 2015-09-24 4 2
5 2015-09-25 5 1
```

Digging further I found that:

```
colname <- "colA"
substitute( cbind( variable = as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4, DF2 ), list(variable = as.name(colname)))
# returns:  cbind(variable = as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4, DF2)
# expected: cbind(colA = as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4, DF2)
```

This example is based on the documentation in the [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f) but I am unable to make it work.  A solution and brief explanation would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setNames()` would be a much safer route (after `cbind()`)

Comment: Thank you Richard.  Excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substitute` doesn’t substitute argument names, which are not variables.

You can use `do.call` instead:

```
b_func <- function (my_dt1, my_dt2, my_col)
    do.call(cbind, setNames(c(list(as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4), DF2),
                            c(my_col, colnames(DF2))))
```

But Richard has a point in his comment: you can simplify this by `cbind`ing first, and assigning names after that:

```
b_func <- function (my_dt1, my_dt2, my_col)
    setNames(cbind(as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4, DF2), c(my_col, colnames(DF2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused in that two arguments to your function, my_dt1 and my_dt2, do not seem to be used. All you seem to be doing is adding a column to DF2? If so, just do this:

```
b_func = function(my_dt, my_col) {
  my_dt[[my_col]] = as.Date("2015-09-21") + 0:4
  my_dt
}
```